# Fine-uploader out of the box questions / errors

Tags: php, fine-uploader

Attempting to run fineuploader right out of the box using the same code that's on the site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fine Uploader Demo</title>
<link href="custom.fineuploader-4.0.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
<script src="custom.fineuploader-4.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
  function createUploader() {
    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
      element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
      request: {
        endpoint: 'server/handleUploads'
      }
    });
  }
  window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Even before beginning to mess around with the endpoint.php I took a look at in a browser and I'm getting the following errors in Firebug:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
}(jQuery));
custom....0.3.js (line 8012)
Error: Cannot find template script at ID 'qq-template'!
...ew Error(qq.format("Cannot find template script at ID '{}'!", options.templateId...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery library is missing in your code
add this in your head tag

```
<head>
.
.
.    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
.
.
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: That solved the jquery error -- but I'm still getting the follwoing error: "Error: Cannot find template script at ID 'qq-template'!
...ew Error(qq.format("Cannot find template script at ID '{}'!", options.templateId..."

Comment: @wfinley And what about `custom.fineuploader-4.0.3.js`? is that loaded?

Comment: Yes - loaded and displays in firebug.

Comment: @wfinley Check out the blog on their site, there's a checklist to go through http://blog.fineuploader.com/ under "Getting Started".

Comment: @wfinley You are missing a template.  This is discussed next to every demo on the home page, and in the documentation as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I included the default template & it's working.  FWIW a better explanation for the Minimal jQuery Demo would be explicitly state that the demo code must also include the default template.